# Random invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript using a COM

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

When I try to access my classic ASP application I get a random error of "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument". The line that causes this error calls a method from a C# component.

Here is the line that breaks in vbscript :

```vb
tmpArray2 = session.get(arrName) 'where arrName is a string
```

Also it cracks at this kind of line too :

```vb
if UBound(session.get("RTT_ID")) <> "-1" then
```

And here is the component code for the get method :

```cs
 public object get(string key)
    {
        if (key == null || IsExpired)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (!SessionData.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var sessionData = GetDbSessionData(key);

            var cachedValue = default(object);
            if (sessionData == null || sessionData.Value == null || sessionData.ValueType == null)
            {
                LogManager.Instance.LogFormat(this, LogLevel.Warning, "Session data not found. SessionId: '{0}'; Key: '{1}'.", this.SessionInfo.Id, key);
                cachedValue = null;
            }
            else
            {
                cachedValue = SessionDataSerializer.Instance.DeserializeSessionData(sessionData.Value, sessionData.ValueType);
            }

            var cachedSessionData = new CachedSessionData();
            cachedSessionData.CachedValue = cachedValue;
            cachedSessionData.DbEntity = sessionData;

            SessionData.Add(key, cachedSessionData);
        }

        RefreshExpirationDate();

        return SessionData[key].CachedValue;
    }
```

Also, what I noticed and I do not know if it is relevant or not, this code cracks a lot on an environment that has 2 servers and makes a balancing between them when the first one is too busy. If I try it on a single server, I managed to broke it only once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your vbscript code is looking for a Variant and you're returning the value of a string... (i.e; get(string key))

Comment: @SteveKline thank you for your answer. How should I change the code so that it will work ? The problem was that some times that call works and other returned that error.

Comment: It's possible when it doesn't work, there's an error because there's no data in the return. You could enable "On Error Resume Next" and use "if err.number <> 0 Then.... err.clear... Error handle stuff here. Then after the if/end if statement to handle the error. On Error Resume Next.

Comment: @SteveKline If the problem is not returning data then just make sure that you have a string `tmpArray2 = session.get(arrName) & ""` and `If UBound(session.get("RTT_ID") & "") <> "-1" Then`, no need for `On Error Resume Next` that's when things get messy especially if you don't switch it back off again with `On Error Goto 0`. I would place the value of `session.get()` in a local variable first before trying to pass it into functions like `UBound()`, that way you can evaluate the result first.

Comment: That's my point, it errors when there's no data or array returned from those... You have to build error handling into the script or accept it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. The problem was that because we wanted to increase our performance we had to serialize every object that was send to the component and deserialize it when we returned it to the vbscript. The issue was that we had one array that was containing other arrays and when we deserialize the array we could not return also the child arrays and that was causing the problem. We used for deserialization the MessageBox library.

Another thing to mention is that on our environment we had 2 servers and we are doing some balancing between them. When the application runs only on one server, the deserialization was ok and we had no problems, but when we switched to the other server we encountered this problem.

Maybe this answer will help others understand what could happen if you receive this type of error.